# Signal/Slot concept Qt and templates... Alternatives?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

Using Qt I get more and more pretty annoyed of it. Qt does not let me use templates in most of its classes since the MOC compiler (or better preprocessor) is run before the actual code generation of c++ takes place.

Is there a reasonable alternative to Qt's internal Singal/Slot concept? I read about boost::signals2 but could not find out if it is preprocessed or not.

Comment: Boost.Signals2 is a pure C++ solution, no preprocessing/precompilation/other such stuff. I've even used it alongside Qt and it works just fine. I ended up with Qt signals for GUI stuff and Boost signals for internal logic.

Comment: Could you provide exact situation, where do you need templates + inheritance from QObject? In most cases, there are possible pretty workarounds. For example - you may use template methods, if they are not slots.

Comment: Maybe [this can help](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq15-academic.html). Also, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26950718/how-to-use-templates-with-qt-signals-and-slots).

Answer (score 2):

> Qt does not let me use templates in most of its classes since the MOC compiler (or better preprocessor) is run before the actual code generation of c++ takes place.

You can use template classes with qt signal-slots, but with next restircions:

1. Template class must be inhereted from QObject
2. Q_OBJECT macro can not be used in template class
3. You cannot define signals and slots in this class - all signals and slots must be in parent class.

Implementation example you can see in [header for QFutureWatcher class](https://github.com/Vitallium/qt5/blob/master/qtbase/src/corelib/thread/qfuturewatcher.h).

> Is there a reasonable alternative to Qt's internal Singal/Slot concept?

If you need to use analog for Qt::DirectConnection only, any implementation from, for example, [here](https://testbit.eu/cpp11-signal-system-performance/) of suitable. If you need Qt::QueuedConnection also, I don't know direct analogs without additional code using. For example, Qt::QueuedConnection may be implemented via boost::signals and boost::asio objects.

> I read about boost::signals2 but could not find out if it is preprocessed or not.

As I understand you question, the preprocessing for boost signals need if not supported variadic templates. From [boost signal.hpp file](https://github.com/gameoverhack/ofxBoost/blob/master/src/lib/boost/signals2/signal.hpp):

```
#ifdef BOOST_NO_VARIADIC_TEMPLATES
#include <boost/signals2/preprocessed_signal.hpp>
#else
#include <boost/signals2/variadic_signal.hpp>
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [sigslot](http://sigslot.sourceforge.net/). It's very similar to Qt signal / slots syntax and it's pure C++:

```
class Switch
{
public:
    signal0<> Clicked;
};

class Light : public has_slots<>
{
public:
    void ToggleState();
};

Switch sw;
Light light;

sw.Clicked.connect(&light, &Light::ToggleState);
```